# How to describe the state of beginning of improving?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Suggestions:

Science was in the state of gathering momentum = is taking off

Science was in the state of embryo = is taking off

Question:

With what word can I describe better the state of very beginning of improving?

Comment: Did you want to use metaphor or are you looking for a word that suggests this, for example ["nascent"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nascent).

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, but it doesn't  really fit this sentence _(Science was ... **nascent** )_

Comment: Max, actually it does ... but that wasn't really my question.  The question was whether you are looking for a particular word, or if you'd rather use a metaphor like "embryonic".

Comment: _Nascent_ is a perfect choice. _"In the late 19th century, the **nascent** science of anthropology was blah blah.."_ However, do you require a verb that can be used felicitously as a present participle (cf. "is taking off"), or an adjective? You already have _"...in its embryonic stage..."_, which is a common metaphor. We also use _poised_ in such constructions: _"Anthropology was **poised** to grow into a full-fledged science..."_

Comment: @Andrew Sorry. Yes, you are right in your assumptions

Answer (score 2):

"Nascent" is often used to describe something that has just been "born" and is expected to grow.

> In the 1990s Internet search was a *nascent* technology that few would have predicted would grow into the dominant entity that is Google.

Depending on what you want to say, you could similarly describe a particular field of scientific study as *nascent*.  Another possibility is *embryonic*, although this implies the subject has "yet to be born" and is still "gestating".

> Despite the hype, some consider self-driving cars to be an *embryonic* technology which has yet to prove its economic viability.

If you want to use idiom, any variation on either "moving fast" or "exploding" will work:

> The technology is *about to take off*
>
> The technology is *about to blow up* / *go nuclear*.